# Address as Entity or Value type in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a doubt regarding `entity vs value type` in Hibernate.
Let's take an example of `User` and `Address`. Here, User is an `entity` and let's take Address as a `component`.

If a user can have only one address, so in this case there will be only one table User and no table for address as it is mapped as component. But, let's say a User may have multiple address, so in this case we need to have another table, apart from user, for that mapping.
Here, I have two options `first`, Address as entity and `second` Address as component.

I understand that there will be no `shared reference` for Address so it need not to be mapped as Entity and map address as component. But, in this case I can map Address as Entity(nobody is stopping me to do that). So, my questions is if I map Address as entity instead of component, will there be any disadvantage of it.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the using the terminology "component," but I can tell you that each entity corresponds to a table.  If you feel that you don't need an `Address` table, then you won't create the corresponding entity class, and vice-versa if you decide you do need a separate table.

Comment: It's difficult to tell for sure without seeing the whole design. Does *anything* else need an Address? If so, a table would seem like the best option (it may anyway). You'll be keeping duplicated data across tables. Meaning every *thing* that needs an address will contain the same fields. That's not great.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils- No, address will not be used by anyone except user.In case of multiple address of a particular user and component mapping, we still require another table. So, in this case, would it better to go with entity or component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a User can have only one Address, then the decision becomes a question of performance, security, and stylistic preference.

As other people have noted, you will get slightly better performance if you map the Address as @Embedded rather than as a separate @Entity. However, it is not possible to answer the question "how much" better will the performance be depends on your use-cases and your data. Things that will affect your performance are, among others, the network latency, the fragmentation (vacuum-status) of your DB, the creation of DB-indexes, and your hibernate configuration (lazy vs. eager loading). And regarding "which is better" - this question cannot really be answered until all of these factors have been taken into consideration. I could tell you that I have a DB with N million users where on average, every user has 15 addresses. I ran a select and retrieved the user in 120 ms and another select to retrieve all addresses of that user in 109 ms. However, that does not help you to answer your case, because your data will be differently distributed, you will experience different network latency, different DB response time.

Reasons to choose mapping as @Embedded:

- High performance is critical for your use-case or application. Do N ms really matter for YOUR application?
- Less disk storage used by the DB.
- You are not creating the DB from scratch. You have a pre-existing DB schema, and you want to access it via Hibernate but cannot modify the schema
- You will always (or very nearly always) access the Address object when loading the User.
- You are guaranteed that you will NEVER need to store multiple addresses for a single user OR you know that you don't need to query users based on the address in a relational manner. This would allow you to serialize a collection of addresses into a clob or blob in your DB. Depending on how you do this, the individual address data can still be accessed and queried, but becomes more interesting.

Reaons to choose mapping as a separate @Entity

- Stylistic preference and the additional latency and overhead is acceptable.
- Want to support the possibility to have multiple Addresses for a single user in the future AND want to filter/query by address data.
- You often need the User for use-cases where the Address is not relevant.
- A related item: Network bandwidth is a concern, and you wish to transfer as little data across the network as absolutely necessary and Address data will only accessed infrequently when loading a user (configured as lazy-load)
- You want to have different DB grant permissions on the two data sets. i.e. one user (in this case, probably a different application) is permitted to update the user's name but not the address, while another is permitted to update both.
- Some users have no address and you want to avoid null checks. An empty collection is your stylistic preference.

Comment: Advantage for `Entity`: If you place address as separate entity, you can alter addresses easier (example: globally clean address data using language rules). When application grows and other tables have references to an address you keep your address data in a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Address Entity has following disadvantages:

- Performance in DB, because you need additional:

  - join for select + foreign key constraint
  - additional primary key generator + primary key index for Address (it will increase DB size too)
- Performance and memory in Hibernate: each entity has a lot of runtime support in hibernate. E.g. hibernate entity cache level 1 - it is enabled by default (transaction level cache). It is cheaper to have one entity with 20 fields than 2 entities with 10 fields in each + realation between them.

Comment: But, if User has multiple addresses, then we need another table(either collection of components case or OneToMany association), so extra table will be required. So, now which one is better; Value type(collection of components) or Entity type(@OneToMany)

Comment: In this case you can achieve only slight improvement on Hibernate level. Also sometime it is reasonable to use json or array data types in some database like postgres.

Comment: What will be the slight improvement on Hibernate level?

Comment: Embeddable objects are still cheaper: they are not referenced from hibernate session directly.

Answer (score 0):

`Java` itself has no concept of composition.

A `class` or `attribute` can’t be marked as a component or composition. The only difference is the object identifier.

A component has no identity, hence the persistent component class requires no identifier property or identifier mapping.

`Hibernate` uses the term component for a user-defined `class` that is persisted to the same table as the owning entity, that is not the case in one-to-one mapping.  Very minor differences between them:  One has an id, the other doesnt and exists within the original `class`.

Comment: Could you please tell me the use case when should we go for component(doesn't have an id) and entity(has id)

Comment: You may want to seperate them out for future cases for separating them from each other.  Also logically its easier to see the different objects and how they are seperate even if they are in the same table.  Each class has its own purpose and responsiblities so they are modeled differently.  It also makes your code a bit more modular.  Also there would be no join so it would also be faster on performance.